# Taking limited characters form paste action on UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a UITextView, on which I restrict a user to enter more than 150 characters. I do this by implementing below method. Now, when user copy more than 150 characters and paste them in this textview, paste action is not allowed due to this method validation. On paste action with more than 150 characters, I want to take first 150 characters and paste it in the UITextView. How can I do this?

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)iTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)iRange replacementText:(NSString *)iText
```

Comment: Show what you actually have so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)iTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)iRange replacementText:(NSString *)iText {
    if (iText.length < 150) {
        return YES;
    }
    iTextView.text = [iText substringToIndex:150];
    return NO;
}
```

In short, check if the input is exceeding the bounds and take the first 150 characters, by taking a substring of the input string. Manually insert it in the text view and return `NO`.

Comment: `iText.length < 150` is incorrect.  You need to count both length of textView and range.  Use `iTextView.text.length + (iText.length - iRange.length)`.